# What is correct way to integrate Ember.js with canvas library like Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, fabricjs

I want to build a restaurant table management and floor layout application using Ember.js and Fabric.js (I'm ready to consider also other canvas frameworks if they provide better support for Ember integration). I already have an Ember application that can manage a list of tables (i.e. TablesRoute to display list of tables, with New ans Edit subroutes etc) and read&write them to JSON backend.

I need to display the tables on the canvas instead of simple list of items. I need two-way binding between Fabric and Ember objects i.e when table is moved or resized on the canvas then I need the object attributes to update in Ember and vica versa when attributes are updated in Ember (by form or update from backend) then I need the graphical representation to change on canvas.

Can somebody point out the right architectural direction how to solve this?

- Where to init the Fabric canvas element? TablesRoute, Application Route? In which method?
- Where to put canvas drawing code? To TablesRoute? TableController? Which method?
- Should I create View elements for canvas? View elements for each table?
- How to solve the two-way binding?
- Any similar example applications out there?

I appreciate all the help I can get on this:)

Comment: did you end up figuring this out? I'm working on something similar and can use some guidance.

Comment: I ended up creating Ember component for this. Component contains array of Tables that are passed from the Handlebars template when using the component. 
Component also contains array of mediator classes. Mediator classes are Ember objects that have two properties: Ember Table object and Fabric Table object. Mediator class also contains Ember Table observers that update Fabric Table object and Fabric Table object event listeners that update Ember Table object. This way all communication between Ember and Fabric is nicely abstracted into separate class.

Comment: Fabric Table objects and Mediator objects are automatically created inside the component by observing changes in the tables array.

Maybe not the best solution, but I tried to separate the Fabric ja Ember code as much as possible and keep synchronization stuff in one place (in Mediator). Unfortunately I can not give out the exact code as it is under NDA.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can init the Fabric canvas element in the controller.
2. You can put canvas drawing code in the controller.

Note1: I use the POD structure in the following sample codes. https://www.ludu.co/course/ember

Note2: I install fabric.js by run command 'bower install fabric --save' in my project.

template.hbs

```
<div><button id="drawRect" {{action 'draw'}}>Draw Rect</button></div>
<div><canvas id="test_fabric" width="200" height="200"></canvas></div>

{{outlet}}
```

controller.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
/* global fabric */
// No import for fabric, it's a global called `fabric`

function drawRect() {
  // create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="test_fabric")
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("test_fabric");

  // create a rectangle object
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20
  });

  // "add" rectangle onto canvas
  canvas.add(rect);
}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    draw: function() {
      //
      drawRect();
    }
  }
});
```

Note: Don’t forget to make JSHint happy by adding a /* global fabric */ to your module. http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies